How can I enable suspend to disk (hibernation / S4) on current Fedora Desktop systems with full disk encryption
I thought that it was once possible natively to hibernate computers but my current machine (Dell XPS 13 9300) on Fedora Linux 39 (Workstation Edition) only offers these in the GNOME session menu

Suspend
Restart…
Power Off…
Log Out…


However, for my working style Suspend To Disk would be far more suitable than Suspend To RAM since I'm often not starting this machine for days yet I don't want to lose the application state.
Suspend to Disk allows me to do that but it doesn't seem to work any more. And the descriptions that worked in releases before Fedora Linux 39 doesn't work for the current release.
I'm also using the default full disk encryption on btrfs that was offered during the installation.
This is what swapon shows:
❯ swapon
NAME            TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/@swap/swapfile file       32G 6.7G   -2
/dev/zram0      partition   8G   8G  100


Does swapon list any swap space available?

@u1686_grawity you are amazingly fast! I just added the output to the description.

If SecureBoot is enabled on many distributions this triggers kernel lockdown mode. lockdown restricts use of hibernation. swap on encrypted block (including luks) might be the only supported mode (so not over a file). I have no proof of what I just wrote, but that would be worth checking. 1st (to avoid being moot): is SecureBoot enabled?

refs: https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/why-does-the-kernel-lockdown-prevent-hibernation/71702/5 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/591488/why-does-the-kernel-lockdown-prevent-hibernation

My experience with Linux in general has been that it has often been difficult, or downright unfeasible, to implement hibernation. Also, as a side note, make full drive images, particularly since full disk encryption is used. An error in a byte or two can make the drive unusable.
